# Google Apps Script json data becomes undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use javascript to display data, but when I get the data from a server function, the data becomes undefined. The data passes jsonlint and trying to use JSON.parse results in an unexpected token error. Why does the type change when it is accessed from javascript, and how do I access the data?

code.gs:

```
function getAppMenus(appID)
{
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Json.json");
  var file = files.next();
  data = file.getAs("json").getDataAsString()
  data = JSON.stringify(data);
  //data = JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log(typeof(data));
  return data;
}
```

The logger says that the type is string

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
  var menuData = google.script.run.getAppMenus("123");
  alert("type is:"+typeof(menuData));
  //menuData = JSON.stringify(menuData);
  //menuData = JSON.parse(menuData);
  //$("#main").append(menuData);
  alert(menuData);
  alert("fin");
});
```

alert says the type is undefined.

log:

```
string

"{\r\n    \"options\": {\r\n        \"option\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"name\": \"asdf\",\r\n                \"stuff\": \"true\"\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"name\": \"fdsa\",\r\n                \"stuff\": \"false\"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n}"
```

Json.json:

```
{
    "options": {
        "option": [
            {
                "name": "asdf",
                "stuff": "true"
            },
            {
                "name": "fdsa",
                "stuff": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
turns out that to load data via JS you need to make an asynchronous call to the server.
In the js:

```
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayButtons).getAppMenus("123");

function displayButtons(data)
{
    dataToDisplay = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(dataToDisplay);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial use of `JSON.parse()` was correcut but you had a syntax error: there was no semicolon after `data = file.getAs("json").getDataAsString()`. This works as you'd expect:

```js
function getAppMenus(appID) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Json.json");
  var file = files.next();
  var data = file.getAs("json").getDataAsString();
  //data = JSON.stringify(data);
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log(typeof data);
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: ah, that wasn't really the problem since semicolons are kind of optional in javascript

Comment: Interesting. If I remove the semicolon I get the error you originally specified in your question. If I put it back, then things work properly: the log shows "object" and then a properly formatted object.